# reading functions variables from the source in main function without passing strict values

Tags: c++

I have a `creatAcc.cpp` file, in this file I made a function that creates an account for the user and inserts the credentials for the user in a file called `register.txt`.

While I'm inserting the code I realized that even if I didn't pass any values inside the function deceleration, I still can read the variables.

For an example, here is the `createAcc.cpp` file

```
  std::string registerPassword, registerName, int randCode; 
    void creatAcc()
     {
    std::ofstream myfile("register.txt");   
    std::cout << "Please insert your name : "; std::cin >> registerName;    
    myfile << registerName << '\n';     
    std::cout << "\n Please insert your password :  "; std::cin >> registerPassword;    
    myfile << registerPassword << '\n';     
    std::cout << "\n we're generating code now for you \n";     
    myfile << randCode; 
}
```

as you can see, I didn't pass any values inside createAcc function, but I add in the

> creatAcc.h   file

As attached :

```
void creatAcc(std::string registerPassword, std::string registerName, int randCode);
```

The question is, when I got to see the main function, I can see the linker knew the variables without my need to pointing it out for him in the createAcc function in `createAcc.cpp` file! as attached :

```
    int main()
{
    int choice ,randCode = rand() % 100 + 1;
    std::string registerPassword, registerName, userName, password;
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "1- Register \n";
        std::cout << "2- Login \n";
        std::cout << "Note : please insert numebr to choose : ";
        std::cin >> choice;
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            creatAcc(registerPassword, registerName, randCode);
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            login(userName, password);
        }
    }
}
```

So the point is, how did the linker know ? is that because of the header file ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"I can see the linker knew the variables"*? I'm not sure if you are misusing the term "linker", "knew", or "the variables" (or maybe all three; in any event linking fails, even after fixing your typo). It would be better to present your objective observations before presenting your interpretation of these observations.

Answer (score 0):

In your `main`, you happen to have declared local variables with the same exact name:

```
std::string registerPassword, registerName, userName, password;
```

You can see this in the 2nd line of your `main`, and they have absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with other variables that happen to have the same name but defined in another source file. And this is what your `main()`'s code uses. These are the variables that get initialized and passed as parameters to the function call.

But since there is no `createAcc()` function, that takes these parameters, the expected result will be a link failure. But the source file with the shown `main` will compile.